# Can't find Skype photos captured on Skype on my MacBook Air

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, photos, skype

I have OS X 10.9.1. I captured a photo using Skype (skype 6.12) and I cannot find the folder holding my images.

I've tried looking for the answer on this website but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I did the search and found it in most peculiar place one can think of.

This is on my MBA with 10.9.2.

```
~/Library/Containers/com.apple.ImageKit.RecentPictureService/Data/Library/Images/Recent Pictures
```

You will find two types of image files there -- TIFF (thumbnail) and standard `.png`

The `.tiff` are converted by Skype to a profile pictures, the `.png` are the originals.

Extra information:

If you need frequent access to that folder but do not want to remember its complicated location

1. Right click on the folder (Recent Pictures)
2. Click on Make Alias
3. Drag the Alias folder to your desktop (you can rename it to what you like)

Answer (score 0):

Yes worked for me to but found there were more steps that listed above

1. find your "library" folder by hitting the option key and clicking “Go” at top icons  (this will make your "library" folder appear in the choices
2. click on "library"
3. click on "Containers"
4. click on "Com.appleImagekit.recentpictureservice"
5. click on "Data"
6. click on "Library"
7. click on "Images"
8. click on "Recent pictures"

Comment: This seems like an unsophisticated restatement of part of Buscar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the contacts pictures in `~/Library/Caches/com.skype.skype/**SkypeUsername**/SKAvatarCache`

The filetype is TIFF:

```
$ file 26BB98C5-E100-41F3-B4FC-13494BAC450A-34407-000040EB90E8B8C7 
26BB98C5-E100-41F3-B4FC-13494BAC450A-34407-000040EB90E8B8C7: TIFF image data,
big-endian, direntries=13, height=256, bps=3, compression=none,
PhotometricIntepretation=RGB, orientation=upper-left, width=256
```